Branching in branch and price
I implement a branch-and-price approach to solve a variant of the bin packing problem. I start with a compact IP formulation and decompose it using Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition into a master problem and a pricing problem. The master problem determines which columns to select, where each column represents an assignment of items to a bin. The pricing problem generates a feasible assignment that satisfies the capacity constraints.
1- I begin with a LP master problem.
2- Initially, I provide a set of columns to the LP master problem, which I refer to as the initial LP master problem. I then apply column generation until no more beneficial columns can be added. At this stage, I refer to the LP master problem as the column generation LP master problem. I solve the IP version of this problem to obtain an UB on the objective function.
3- At this point, the root node?!, I need to branch. My questions are:

-- Which problem should I consider for branching: the initial LP master problem or the column generation LP master problem?
4- Instead of branching on if a column would be selected or not. I plan to use the Ryan and Foster (1981) branching rule to find two items $i, j$ such that $0 < \alpha_{ij} < 1$, where $\alpha_{ij}$ indicates whether items $i$ and $j$ are assigned to the same bin or not (1 or 0). The Ryan and Foster branching rule selects the pair $(i, j)$ for which $\alpha_{ij}$ is closest to 0.5 in the solution of (column generation) LP master problem. We then generate two new nodes by setting $\alpha_{ij}$ to 0 and 1, respectively.

-- At this point, should I branch on the next level using the pair $(i,j)$ which has s $\alpha$ closest to 0.5, a set of pairs with $0 < \alpha < 1$ arranged in order of closeness to 0.5 (best-first search), or all possible combinations of $i$ and $j$? My concern is whether the algorithm will still reach optimality if I do not consider the last option.
After branching, we update the master problem and the pricing problem to reflect the selected node. We use column generation to find the best possible solution. If the objective value of this best possible solution is larger than the UB, we prune the branch. Otherwise, if this solution is integer, we update the UB. If the solution is not integer, we branch again, continuing this process until the entire tree is covered.

"Which problem should I consider for branching: the initial LP master problem or the column generation LP master problem?" I think that the proper question would be "Which variables should I consider for branching: the $x$ variables of the master problem or the column generated variables $\lambda$? Which, in a common bin-packing B&P would be a bin setting.".+

If so, firstly, you must to guarantee that you have all $x$ variables for representing the optimal integer solution, if this criteria is met, then you proceed with the generation of the $\lambda$ variables (as you greatly presented). As for the branching, fixing a $\lambda_k$ variable may be  troublesome, since you may endup with problems when performing the pricing, since you will have to find a way to map the dual of the branching constraint ($\lambda_k \leqslant 0$ or $\lambda_k \geqslant 1$) into the pricing subproblem.

"At this point, should I branch on the next level using the pair $(i,j)$ which has $\alpha$ closest to $0.5$, a set of pairs with $0<\alpha<1$ arranged in order of closeness to $0.5$ (best-first search), or all possible combinations of $i$ and $j$? My concern is whether the algorithm will still reach optimality if I do not consider the last option." Check section 3.3 of 10.1287/ijoc.2018.0867.
